# I want the call keep play using vonage after action button

Tags: node.js, vonage

I have a script using Node.js that will display input digits entered by a user using Vonage in the telegram bot and under the message there are two buttons I want to handle them when click correct I want the conversation to continue in this code after pressing yes the call end.
I try with chatGPT he gives me these two functions `vonage.voice.update` and `vonage.voice.updateCall` but I think they are in the old version.

```
const { Vonage } = require("@vonage/server-sdk");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const TelegramBot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
app.use(express.json());
const axios = require("axios");

const vonage = new Vonage({
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  apiSecret: "apiSecret",
  applicationId: "applicationId",
  privateKey: "privateKey",
});

app.get("/webhook/answer", (req, res) => {
    // Create NCCO with greeting message
    const { status } = req.body;
    if (status === "answered") {
      // Send message "The receiver answered"
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, "The receiver answered");
      return;
    }
    const ncco = [
      {
        action: "talk",
        bargeIn: true,
        text: `Hello Sir , press 1 to continue `,
      },
      {
        action: "input",
        maxDigits: 1,
        timeOut: 10,
        eventUrl: [
          "event_url",
        ],
      },
    ];
    res.json(ncco);
  });


 vonage.voice
    .createOutboundCall({
      to: [{ type: "phone", number: phoneNumberTo }],
      from: { type: "phone", number: phoneNumberFrom },
      answer_url: [
        "answer_url",
      ],
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const activeCallUUID = response.uuid; // Store the active call UUID
      console.log("Outbound call created successfully:", activeCallUUID);

      // Use the activeCallUUID for further processing or store it in a suitable location
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error making outbound call:", error);
    });
 app.post("/webhook/dtmf", (req, res) => {
    const dtmfDigits = req.body.dtmf;
      if (dtmfDigits.length === 6) {
        ncco = [{
          action: 'talk',
          text: 'Please wait while we connect you to',
          bargeIn: true,
        
        },
        {
          action : "conversation",
          name : conversationName,
          startOnEnter : false,
          musicOnHoldUrl : ["mp3_url"]
        }
        ]

        bot.sendMessage(chatId, `DTMF digits entered: ${dtmfDigits}`, {
          reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
              [{ text: "Correct", callback_data: `correct:${req.body.uuid}` }],
              [{ text: "Not Correct", callback_data: "not_correct" }],
            ],
            resize_keyboard: true,
          },
        });
        console.log(ncco);
        res.json(ncco);
      }
      res.status(200).end();
  bot.on("callback_query", (query) => {
    const callbackData = query.data;
    const [callbackAction, callUUID] = callbackData.split(":");
    if (callbackAction === "correct") {
     
    }
  });
});
```

I want when I press the button correct the call continues and I want a new talk start exp "please wait" and audio start. thank you so much